Requesting Multiple Permissions in MAUI failing (Worked with Xamarin.Essentials)
I've migrated from Xamarin.Essentials to MAUI, and the RequestAsync's are failing to return from the await to run the rest of the function. At the moment, the app needs to start 4 times before it's "normal", as it requests one permission on each start, and eventually runs through the whole block without requesting a permission.
await Utilities.AppPermissions.RequestAppPermissions();
        public static async Task<bool> RequestAppPermissions()
        {
            try
            {
                //First round of location permissions
                Serilog.Log.Debug($"Check 'LocationWhenInUse' Permission");
                if (await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>() != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    Serilog.Log.Debug($"Request'LocationWhenInUse' Permission");
                    await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
                    Serilog.Log.Error("This is never run!");
                }
               
                //Request LocationAlways Permission
                Serilog.Log.Debug($"Check 'LocationAlways' Permission");
                if (await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>() != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    Serilog.Log.Debug($"Request 'LocationAlways' Permission");
                    await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>();
                    Serilog.Log.Error("This is never run!");
                }

                //Notifications
                if (OperatingSystem.IsAndroidVersionAtLeast(33))
                {
                    Serilog.Log.Debug($"Check 'PostNotifications' Permission");
                    if (await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.PostNotifications>() != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                    {
                        Serilog.Log.Debug($"Request 'PostNotifications' Permission");
                        await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.PostNotifications>();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Serilog.Log.Fatal(ex, "Failed to request permissions");
                return false;
            }
        }

Google searches have been of no help so far. In theory its supposed to work, but isn't. All nuget packages have been upgraded to latest as of today (Sep 15, and VS is 2022 17.11.3)

You can also refer to this official doc: Platform helpers.

5 min after posting this, after spending way too much time trying to figure it out, I realised that I somehow had deleted OnRequestPermissionsResult from the activity. Adding it back, and it now works as it should. Doh!
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

